# ZendFramework Zend_Form_Element_File setDestination vs rename filter

Tags: zend-framework

The code says Zend_Form_element_File::setDestination() is deprecated and to use the rename filter. However the rename filter is currently codes such that when path is set, only temporary name is given. Original filename is lost.

```
<?php
$file = new Zend_Form_Element_File();
$file->setDestination('/var/www/project/public');
?>
```

vs

```
<?php
$file = new Zend_Form_Element_File();
$file->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => '/var/www/project/public'));
?>
```

Any solution to upload files so that it preserves original filename structure but checks for  existing file and appends _1.ext or _2.ext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submitting the form you can inspect the `$_FILES['file_element']['name']` check for existing files and then set the rename filter on your form element before calling the :

`$form->getValues()/isValid() or $form->file_element->receive()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the name of the file after upload and then add the Rename filter then.  Eg:

```
if ($form->file->isUploaded()) {
    $fileinfo = $form->file->getFileInfo();
    $filename = $fileinfo['file']['name'];
    $extn = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $uploadname = $this->_makeFilename($formData, $extn);
    $uploadfilepath = UPLOADED_FILES_PATH . '/' . $uploadname;
    $form->file->addFilter('Rename', $uploadfilepath);
    $receiveStatus = $form->file->receive();
}
```